# Google analytics stores username and password as a part of url

Tags: security, url, meteor, google-analytics, credentials

### Issue Context:

I am using **meteor js** for a mobile app.
I have hooked it up with **google analytics** calls and basically I am using two type of calls:

1. Screen views
2. Events

Screen views are just fine, but I'm facing an issue with the events.

When I go to *Behavior -> Events -> Screens*, in the google analytics dashboard, I can see the URL of every page that has triggered an event under the **Screen Name** column. My problem is that the page URLs for my login page look something like this:

```
meteor.local/login?username=*******&password=+++++++&rememberMe=on
```

Where ******* is an actual **username** and +++++++ is the corresponding **password**!

---

### Reason:

Since I have to **share this analytics account** with multiple people, **I do not want this information to be available** over here.

---

### Clues:

**CLUE 1:**

I used to do *GET* http calls, but I have changed them all to *POST* and it still has not fixed the issue as I expected it not to pass plain parameters through URL anymore.

**CLUE 2:**

I've noticed that the default google analytics js framework is working with *http* and not *https*. I was wondering if it is calling the analytics server with a *GET* as well. If so, is there anyway to change that?

**CLUE 3:**

Here is how I am initiating the **GA** instance:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', googleKey, 'auto');
```

**CLUE 4:**

I have also noticed that these URLs are getting captured very occasionally. E.g. in the pas 12,500 unique events (about 30,000 total events) it has captured just 9 URLs with the username and password. The remaining 12,491 events have

```
meteor.local/login
```

OR

```
meteor.local/--
```

OR

```
localhost/--
```

as the Screen Name.

**CLUE 5:**

I have also put 4 *"search and replace"* **global filters** on the analytics account to search for this string

> meteor.local/.*

and replace it with this one

> meteor.local/concealedURI

This does not seem to be working either.
I have added this filter on 4 different fields (Since **I still really don't know where the URLs are coming from**):

1. Host Name
2. Page Title
3. Referral
4. Request URI

**CLUE 6:**

This is how I am calling the **GA** instance to send the event:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', eventName);
```

Comment: Is there any commonality amongst the events passing the user and password? is it possibly the `rememberMe=on` flag causing this to happen? or people arriving from a specific page or referrering url?

Comment: @PhilipPryde I don't think its the `rememberMe` flag, because I'm only seeing these URLs rarely and that _Remember Me_ feature is one of the most widely used ones on this app. These are all coming from the login page though.

Comment: Your forms should be using `POST` instead of `GET` to log in. That way the login credentials do not appear in the URL.

Comment: @Mike As I've said in **Clue1**, I have changed all of them to `POST` already but it has not changed anything.

Comment: @MaxFot You're not using `POST` if the variables are appended to the URL... unless you're still looking at *old* results where the parameters were in the URL. In which case, maybe this link would help: http://blog.crazyegg.com/2013/03/29/remove-url-parameters-from-google-analytics-reports/

Comment: As a stop gap measure go to your view settings and add "username" and "password" in the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" field. But this is really something that needs to be fixed on the application level. It's not only a security breach, it also quite probably violates Googles TOS (if username and password are not personally identifiable data then what is).

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the help and link you provided. Unfortunately I am running a meteor app. This means that I do not have access to the "Exclude URL query parameters" option that is being used in that link. Since I am using meteor, I am actually compiling a webpage as an App, thus I still have URLs.

Comment: @Mike And I double checked all my code, I do not have a single GET call!

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks for the comment. As I told Mike above, I do not have access to "Exclude URL Query Parameters" since I am using Meteor js and this is not being tracked in google analytics as a website but an App.

Comment: @MaxFot Forms, by default, use `GET`. If you left out the `method` parameter, it will use `GET`.

Comment: @Mike I am not passing any data through any forms. I just make a http POST call. I'm afraid this is not getting captured as as a part of the http call URL, but the google analytics is saving the screen name of the page that triggers any event and in my case (since I am using meteor) the screen name is the URL of that page which contains username and password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. So, I had to run a lot of experiments and try out different things to solve this issue.

**After trying all the things that I have described in the question**, I finally found a way to address this problem.

The **main cause** of this problem was that I was using a google analytics account set to track an **App**, to capture the data from an app that was built with **meteor js** (which basically utilizes **cordova**).

Using meteor means that **my app's screens are actually web pages** rendered as a mobile app. It seems like meteor uses URLs to navigate through these screens.

On the other hand, google analytics looks at (and captures) the screen name of an app's page, when an event is triggered from that page. In **native apps** this screen name will be something similar to "About us", "Contact Us", "Home", etc.

Now since a meteor app is not the same, **the screen name returned by meteor is actually the URL of the page that has triggered the event.**

This does not have anything to do with the http calls (Whether or not they are GET or POST), because it is the local URL used by meteor for navigating that is being passed down to google analytics and not any http calls.

---

## Solutions

### 1.

If I had the google analytics account set as a **web page** tracker, I could have access to "Exclude URL Query Parameters" field and I could potentially exclude username and password as was suggested by @Mike and @PhilipPryde in the comments.
However, I needed to use google analytics set as an **app** tracker. So, this did not work for me.

**Failed**

---

### 2.

I did put a filter on the whole **view** in the google analytics and searched for meteor.local/.* and replaced that with hiddenURL. The filters on

- Host Name
- Page Title
- Referral
- Request URI

did not work.

But when I put the same filter on

- **Screen Label**

field, it worked.

However, this only looked at the screen names returned by screen view hits and not the event. Thus, this did not actually solve my issue either.

**Failed**

---

### Finally, I had to do this:

There is a method call on GA instance that lets you **set different options up**. I ended up using this:

```
ga('set', 'screenName', 'hiddenURL');
```

This changed the screen name to "hiddenURL". So, **I used this before every event** and it worked for me.
My code for sending events to google analytics looked like this:

```
ga('set', 'screenName', 'hiddenURL');
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', eventName);
```

**PS:**

This changes the screen name that was showing up in real-time reports of google analytics to "hiddenURL", whenever someone triggered an event. But, it changes back to a screen name as soon as they go to another page. So, it would not also mess with any of your screen view data either, since it is not being captured as a screen view.

Of course that is because, I pass the screen name to my GA instance every time I send a screen view. So it looks like this:

```
sendScreenViewToGA = function (screenName) {
    ga('send', 'screenview', {
        'appName': 'Something',
        'screenName': screenName,
        'appVersion': x.x
    });
}
```

If I had used the screen name, that is being set on the environment tight now, I would have ended up with all my screen names in analytics set to "hiddenURL".

---

I really hope this post will help others with same issues and save them some time.

Comment: This was an excellently documented answer to a very complicated problem. Thanks.